# How to show selected option in bootstrap 4?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I want to select an option from the dropdown when I click one of the options it will always show the English option at the top. I want the selected language to be at the top when selected.

**This is my code **

```
    <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-lg-center ml-lg-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <img src="../assets/img/flags/uk.png" class="rds__flag-lang pr-2">English
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['kh','home']"><img src="../assets/img/flags/kh.png" class="rds__flag-lang pr-2">Khmer</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['cn','home']"><img src="../assets/img/flags/ch.png" class="rds__flag-lang pr-2">China</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['en','home']"><img src="../assets/img/flags/uk.png" class="rds__flag-lang pr-2">English</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind click event and call a function on click, then store selected item value in variable and use that variable in you html template file

```
<ul class="navbar-nav align-items-lg-center ml-lg-auto">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <img src="../assets/img/flags/uk.png" class="rds__flag-lang pr-2"> {{selectedItem}}
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['kh','home']" (click)="onChangeLang('Khmer')"><img src="../assets/img/flags/kh.png" class="rds__flag-lang pr-2">Khmer</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['cn','home']" (click)="onChangeLang('China')"><img src="../assets/img/flags/ch.png" class="rds__flag-lang pr-2">China</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['en','home']" (click)="onChangeLang('English')"><img src="../assets/img/flags/uk.png" class="rds__flag-lang pr-2">English</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

In ts class file

```
selectedItem: string;

onChangeLang(selectedItem: string) {
    this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
}
```

You can refer angular docs https://angular.io/guide/user-input

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax

Answer (score 0):

Do it the smartest way by creating an array of select options, then use [NgFor](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngFor)

here is the .ts code

```
 selectOptions = [{lang:'Khmer', flag:'kh.png', route:'kh'},
                  {lang:'China', flag:'ch.png', route:'ch'},
                  {lang:'English', flag:'uk.png', flag:'uk'}];

 selectedOption: string;

 onChangeLang(selectedOption: string) {
    this.selectedOption= selectedOption;
 }
```

and the template part

```
  <ul class="navbar-nav align-items-lg-center ml-lg-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <img src="../assets/img/flags/{selectedOption.flag}" class="rds__flag-lang pr-2"> {{selectedOption.lang}}
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a *ngFor="let option of selectOptions" 
             class="dropdown-item" 
            [routerLink]="[option.route,'home']" 
            (click)="onChangeLang(option)">
               <img src="../assets/img/flags/{{selectedOption.flag}}" 
             class="rds__flag-lang pr-2" >{{option.lang}}</a> 
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```